# diabetic help program for glucose monitoring

Tags: windows

i am a diabetic and one thing i am having difficulty in finding  is an app that works with the one touch verio glucose reader or any reader for that matter , and since there are so many diabetics in the world i think that there should be at least a few app for glicimia control mapping and for health care ,fitness , a live style as there are for windows in the windows store and some of them free.

Thanks for your attention 
Richard Installman

Comment: Try android or online, web based apps ;)

Comment: http://www.mendosa.com/software.htm

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was created 8 years ago to attract spam answers and has received upvotes only form those spammers.